# given a date and a cron expression can you validate that the date is part of the cron expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cron

I have a cron expression and i need to check if a certain Date is part of it.(meaning the cron would trigger at that Date)
(using nodejs)

Comment: use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cron-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser) package and do something like this:

```
const isDateMatchesCronExpression = (expression, date, scope = 'second') => {
  scope = ['second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day', 'month', 'weekday'].indexOf(scope.toLowerCase());
  try {
    const data = cronParser.parseExpression(expression).fields;

    if (scope <= 0 && !data.second.includes(date.getSeconds())) return false;
    if (scope <= 1 && !data.minute.includes(date.getMinutes())) return false;
    if (scope <= 2 && !data.hour.includes(date.getHours())) return false;
    if (scope <= 3 && !data.dayOfMonth.includes(date.getDate())) return false;
    if (scope <= 4 && !data.month.includes(date.getMonth() + 1)) return false;
    if (scope <= 5 && !data.dayOfWeek.includes(date.getDay())) return false;

    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`isDateMatchesCronExpression error: ${e}`);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a package like [croner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/croner), you can implement this function:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} cronExpression The cron expression. See https://croner.56k.guru/usage/pattern/
 * @param {Date} [timestamp] The timestamp to check. Defaults to the current time.
 * @returns {Number} The number of seconds until the next cron run.
 */
export function getSecondsUntilNextCronRun(cronExpression, timestamp = new Date()) {
  // Required for seconds precision
  const adjustedTimestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() - 1000);
  
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/croner
  const cronJob = new Cron(cronExpression);
  const nextRunTime = cronJob.nextRun(adjustedTimestamp);

  const secondsDelta = (nextRunTime - adjustedTimestamp) / 1000;
  return secondsDelta;
}
```

Then you can just call it like this:

```js
getSecondsUntilNextCronRun("* * 14 * * *", new Date("2023-10-20T14:30:00")) <= 1; // true
getSecondsUntilNextCronRun("* 45 * * * *", new Date("2023-10-20T14:30:00")) <= 1; // false
```

Additionally, you can also have a convenient function like this:

```js
const isCronJobScheduled = (expression, time) => getSecondsUntilNextCronRun(expression, time) <= 1;
```